# ViewBag behind the scenes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, viewbag

This is code from the Contoso University online example:

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Department department = departmentService.GetById(id);
        PopulateAdministratorDropDownList(department.PersonID);
        return View(department);
    }

     // POST: /Department/Edit/5
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Edit(Department department)
     {
       try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
             departmentService.Update(department); 
             return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
           //Log the error (add a variable name after DataException)
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem 
               persists, see your system administrator.");
        }
        PopulateAdministratorDropDownList(department.PersonID);
        return View(department);
     }


     private void PopulateAdministratorDropDownList(object selectedAdministrator = null)
     {
         var administrators = instructorService.GetAll().OrderBy(i => i.LastName);
         ViewBag.PersonID = new SelectList(administrators, "PersonID", "FullName",    
             selectedAdministrator);
     }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("PersonID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PersonID)
</div>
```

My question is: if in the View we are not accessing the ViewBag.PersonID (we just create a DropDownList, that generates an html select list with the ID="PersonID", without any default selected value), how the hell the ViewBag.PersonID property is binded to that DropDownList? What's happening behind the scenes? This looks like magic!!!

The second question is when Posting the data, I think the controller searches in the view for any html form field whose ID matches a property in the model and that's how we get the selected Department.PersonID on the postback, even if the view code doesn't reference the model (somtheing like model => model.PersonID) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behind the scenes:

The view is calling `Html.DropdownList(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, string optionLabel)` which eventually ends up calling `SelectExtensions.SelectInternal(htmlHelper, metadata, optionLabel, expression, selectList, allowMultiple, htmlAttributes1)`   This checks `selectList1` for null, and if if it is, it calls `SelectExtensions.GetSelectData(htmlHelper, name)` which does the magic part of checking the View data for a key matching the name you passed in.

Posting:

Your assumptions here are pretty much right, but the in addition to form fields the framework will also check the query string and route data and any other IValueProvider that is plugged in to the pipe line.